# Loading a table in numpy with row- and column-indices, like in R?

Tags: python, numpy, header, row-number, indices

I would like to load a table in numpy, so that the first row and first column would be considered text labels. Something equivalent to this R code:

```
read.table("filename.txt", row.header=T)
```

Where the file is a delimited text file like this:

```
   A    B    C    D
X  5    4    3    2
Y  1    0    9    9
Z  8    7    6    5
```

So that read in I will have an array:

```
[[5,4,3,2],
 [1,0,9,9],
 [8,7,6,5]]
```

With some sort of:
    rownames   ["X","Y","Z"]
    colnames ["A","B","C","D"]

Is there such a class / mechanism?

Comment: See [example 2](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) from the `numpy.loadtxt` documentation.

Comment: Must it be native numpy, or can you allow pandas? You had tagged this matplotlib.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numpy arrays aren't perfectly suited to table-like structures. However, [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe)s are.

For what you're wanting, use [`pandas`.](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

For your example, you'd do

```
data = pandas.read_csv('filename.txt', delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)
```

As a more complete example (using `StringIO` to simulate your file):

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

f = StringIO("""A    B    C    D
X  5    4    3    2
Y  1    0    9    9
Z  8    7    6    5""")
x = pd.read_csv(f, delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)

print 'The DataFrame:'
print x

print 'Selecting a column'
print x['D'] # or "x.D" if there aren't spaces in the name

print 'Selecting a row'
print x.loc['Y']
```

This yields:

```
The DataFrame:
   A  B  C  D
X  5  4  3  2
Y  1  0  9  9
Z  8  7  6  5
Selecting a column
X    2
Y    9
Z    5
Name: D, dtype: int64
Selecting a row
A    1
B    0
C    9
D    9
Name: Y, dtype: int64
```

Also, as @DSM pointed out, it's very useful to know about things like `DataFrame.values` or `DataFrame.to_records()` if you do need a "raw" numpy array.  (`pandas` is built on top of numpy. In a simple, non-strict sense, each column of a `DataFrame` is stored as a 1D numpy array.)

For example:

```
In [2]: x.values
Out[2]:
array([[5, 4, 3, 2],
       [1, 0, 9, 9],
       [8, 7, 6, 5]])

In [3]: x.to_records()
Out[3]:
rec.array([('X', 5, 4, 3, 2), ('Y', 1, 0, 9, 9), ('Z', 8, 7, 6, 5)],
      dtype=[('index', 'O'), ('A', '<i8'), ('B', '<i8'), ('C', '<i8'), ('D', '<i8')])
```

Comment: And then you could use `data.values` to get an `ndarray` out of it or `data.to_records()` to get a `recarray`, etc.  (Although IMHO numpy's structured arrays are just useful enough to lure you into trying to do more with them than they're really designed for..)

Comment: @DSM - Good point! (And I completely agree on the point about structured arrays. The "..just useful enough to lure you into..." is a rather apt quote!)